# Cucumber 5: Get step name from feature file excluding gherkin syntax (given, when, then, and)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

So I need to get the test step descriptions after the gherkin syntax

> ```
> Feature: User trades stocks   Scenario: User requests a sell before close of trading
> Given I have 100 shares of MSFT stock
>    And I have 150 shares of APPL stock
>    And the time is before close of trading
> ```

So what I really need is to get the

`I have 100 shares of MSFT stock`

`I have 150 shares of APPL stock`

`the time is before close of trading`

**I found these as I update the cucumber to v5.0.0-RC1:**

- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/1323

Can someone help me with a snippet? What is the object that needs to be passed to the AfterStep and BeforeStep?

Comment: The data u are looking for is contained in `gherkin.ast.Step`, the way to access it is through a custom formatter. Implement `EventListener` or `ConcurrentEventListener` and setup handlers for different events u are interested in. Have a look at the HTMLFormatter - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/formatter/HTMLFormatter.java

Comment: @Grasshopper the link seems to be broken. I'm using cucumber v5.0.0-RC1. Can you help me with a snippet how to implement it? :|

Comment: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/cucumber/core/plugin/HTMLFormatter.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code solution (in serviceHook class) for cucumber v4.3.1.

```
PickleStepTestStep currentStep;
private int counter = 0;

@BeforeStep
public void getStepName(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {

    Field f = scenario.getClass().getDeclaredField("testCase");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    TestCase r = (TestCase) f.get(scenario);

    List<PickleStepTestStep> stepDefs = r.getTestSteps()
            .stream()
            .filter(x -> x instanceof PickleStepTestStep)
            .map(x -> (PickleStepTestStep) x)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    currentStep = stepDefs.get(counter);

        System.out.println(currentStep.getStepText());

    }

@AfterStep
public void afterStep(Scenario scenario) {
    counter += 1;
}
```